# SN7404 inverter strange input low current

Tags: inverter, ttl

When I connect the SN7404 pin 1 to ground and measure the current, the current is nearly zero (5uA at most). I would expect the input low current (I_{IL}) is usually around 1mA magnitude. I tested to drive an LED using pin 2, the LED is on, but input pin still almost zero current. I tried different SN7404 chip, same results.

I tested 7400, 74LS245, etc the current is around 1mA magnitude when I ground the inputs pins.

any thoughts why the 7404 input low current is nearly zero? thanks!

Here is the chip:
http://www.jameco.com/z/7404-Major-Brands-IC-7404-Hex-Inverter-DIP-14_49040.html

Comment: How are you doing the measurement?

Comment: connect multimeter positive to pin 1, and multimeter negative to ground. other 74xx chips are normal, about 1mA flow out when group the input pin.

Comment: And do you have power on the chip?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't give you an 'HC04 or 'HCT04 instead?

Comment: yes, the power is connected, it can drive LED bright.

Comment: very positive it is not CMOS chip, I even double checked the label with mag glass, unless the chip factory printed wrong label on the chip.

Comment: Is the chip working? That is, can you provide a TTL low and high to pin 1, and see the opposite on pin 2?

Comment: it is working, ground pin 1, pin 2 light LED (with 1K current limiting res). connect pin 1 to 5V, pin 2 LED is off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/SN7404) has to say about the circuit:

[image: 7404 circuit]

It is not possible for this circuit to source less than about 1 mA into a low input.

So what you have cannot be an SN7404. Apparently, you got a recycled chip, and whoever re-applied the label used the wrong one.

To confirm that you have a CMOS chip, measure the output current in both high and low states.

Comment: Those ICs have a pretty wide tolerance on those resistors so the current will vary from 1 mA quite a bit. But I don't think the OP's got the wrong chip, I think it's more likely that their multimeter isn't up to it. That's my punt.

Comment: I just measured the output, it is 5V! It should be a CMOS chip, despite the chip label is "(O3CS89K E4) SN7404". I bought it from Jameco, probably recycled mis-labelled chip.

Comment: @Alex Please add a photo to the question.